# How to turn the blue placement text in Xcode to text?

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5

Is there a way to turn the blue placement text in Xcode to actual text? It is quite tedious to have to type it out when I have a block.[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the caret position you show, doesn't:

<kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Return</kbd>

do what you want?

Answer (score 2):

With the blue replacement text selected, hit return.

Answer (score 2):

Press `Tab` key, when the blue text is selected, press `Enter`.

Answer (score 0):

- **Select** using <kbd>tab</kbd> or **mouse click**
- press **<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Return</kbd>**

That will insert the text